# Send packet (icmp or else) through network interface, bypassing routing table

Tags: linux, bash, ping, network-interface

I'd like to send packet (icmp or else) through a specific network interface, bypassing the routing table.

Context: I'm connected through several interfaces to various endpoint. Some of them are able to route my traffic towards internet if I add a route to them.
I don't want to touch the routing table (as it is a global system feature, and that I'm testing in parallel the devices for speed reason).

Initially, I thought a simple `ping -I DEVICE -r ANY_IP_ONINTERNET` would do the trick. But it doesn't: packets are NOT sent to the selected device as I would have expected and the command fails... `tcpdump` on the other end does not catch any packets: **the packets don't seem to** even **be sent to the interface** in the first place despite my explicit command.

**When I add a route prior the ping, everything works as expected**. But I would like to avoid this... And then, the `-I DEVICE -r` is not required anymore.

- **can somebody explain me why it doesn't work ?**, and
- in what case the use of `-I DEVICE` or `-r` actually works and is usefull ?

Note: I'm testing this with different VPNs with `tapX` and `tunX` devices.

**EDIT:** I tried combination with/without `-r` and using `-I DEVICE` or `-I IP_ADDR_DEVICE`. With no more success.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use option `-I` with IP address of your device.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried this and it didn't work neither... I added this information to the main question. Thanks to help me completing my question.